# Translating from React to Mithril 2? (a Meiosis example)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mithril.js

The code is an example we found in [Meiosis SAM-patern page](https://meiosis.js.org/docs/sam-pattern.html). It is done in React, I am translating to Mithril 2.0.0-rc.4.

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.navigateTo = pageId =>
      pipe(
        preventDefault,
        () => this.props.actions.navigateTo(pageId)
      );
    this.state = this.props.states();
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const setState = this.setState.bind(this);
    this.props.states.map(state => {
      setState(state);
    });
  }

  render() {
    const state = this.state;
    const { actions } = this.props;
    const active = pageId => state.pageId === pageId ? " active" : "";
    const Component = pages[state.pageId];
```

First, We just change **render** to **view**, but what about the **constructor** (Mithril is a POJO so we don't have it) and the **componentDidMount**?
Beyond changing **componentDidMount** to **oncreate**, what is this code doing? and Is it needed in Mithril?

```
const App = {
  oncreate: ???
  view: ({ attrs: { state, actions } }) =>
    const active = pageId => state.pageId === pageId ? " active" : "";
    const Component = pages[state.pageId];
```

Comment: (Mithril gitter) @fuzetsu: "...use oninit OR a closure as the equivalent for a constructor in both v1 and v2."

Answer (score 1):

The resulted code is smaller/concise using mithril's **closure component**.

As I spected, the **componentDidMount** code is not needed.

```
const App = (actions) => {
  const navigateTo = pageId =>
      pipe(
       preventDefault,
        () => actions.navigateTo(pageId)
      )
  return {
    view({ attrs: { state } }) {
      const active = pageId => state.pageId === pageId ? " active" : ""
      const Component = pages[state.pageId]
```

And the right way to create/call the component is:

```
const View = App(actions) // comp. factory
m.mount(document.getElementById("app"), {
  view: () => m(View, { state: states()})
})
```

You can compare the [React](https://flems.io/#0=N4IgtglgJlA2CmIBcA2ADAGhAZ3ggxgC7xTIgB2AhgG4QDmlhEA9uQLTwAelYADggDoAVthBYAZhASikAbVBUwiJBRr1GLdlx794w0Vnyti5QmQD0AKgAEdWMwBGlWNYBK8SkQxuPRACIA8gCy3uKwAJ5Q3gHWluYAOuSJ5ubWbGzWAKpMsBCE4dZGUPCJiUbk2ITWvBC88NYAvNYAFAJt4hUAlI0AfNYQ5LwArlUNPYnW1h3YAgBOJEP48M3N1M5D8KHk3WNT5Kvr8J3eA8OEnQDcpeTlldXz1PCmfvDilEOwo9bw1KN9wBNvr8BLwHk9CC83h9CM1LoD5oQhrNyEDCFdyABfdHJVLpawAQV4-Ag+A0rEKzGK11uVUoRMa1gBKOsAElyHkIM4kC0dn1mkzJpNeJQ6PAWVBufEQAAJZhKAAKIpKYkBk3sdAG3IFgsmQ1wyJ48ElIClGFVguF2GwAHdmLMJdYpU7mZMMYCMcdAfiiJpsNyhrwoIx6rt+eaqLQGMQACrMbnC0Xi3rWANB4j86pKpMes0u6zqzUp-XJ1PBjN6+CzbwJsUOqWyhVKqXWHPmisGpTctawDa9c26wNl4D55ga8jcgLl-WKI3Wbu9j0tz15y02u0O+ch8Z5gdp5bDgvj6yT4er232ruHJdL3M69XMEbc2F9ncpwfp7U63X67nkD6wW8v0mNNKF-f9AKAmtxWNBt4EVUVnSA1s83sSgoD8RhQJ5F8gNwQhowgJQHxhftBWfXZSw-awQONaMAAt6hA6w6MobBrAceAnhHNCSAEZtkKAyYAEYAFY0DQUjOndKTMWxcgUjSDJ4PgbBqVgVi2Ng5Tvk4EwoDY9xPEIAQAGE5V4VhwUZeEnmKWZn0-awESRFFmlIgAeKAIGobdBOsAA5NQo3qQhmGsShM1FdiCnwXJ8AAawGOhrHJQgGP6YgwDYygHGYR4+NfdzzC8nzzThZk3UxNSNOsAAZUcBm0rg9IM3xjLMvhLNMazmXmcg7Ic80aUZaxKmDFsGTSiAZlBZheGwdEdWc5EWg8krfMEzzvJ6eqxyK9bSMmdzxDtMBCnUq1AqUBopQjJxZjYE7ZjAKUNr8rbqHOjSrvgG6QCesA2DoWYH14V7Dq-dzThGCGgPyOo-uIXTEL8r9Yu+w0-oBthykIEHYBR1GLXUpY6OYWA7L+9sZ0Jom50OBpgDG4gBEPARqcNSq6cFVgTJY8hRUZn4-lhwSjN9dnp0NZphYEQhKFmUVjM3GTuddUXJnMN7NuK7bRY+r7LsxqVseB0HwdfICocGGHLcE+HfqlM911pon0aN66TdOnHjHx13Uf4Tx4DJinKz+537X9vzN0Z5m9DZiOoC5tXef5wXgGFnC1cmcXWBmjTzygGXgXlxX4GVw5VbV5Oia1-XddKu2jocEZQqSJvBQdv7sCGBxIEIKO0Yu7Afr+hxCBRcf2FBQiFfCQedV5uL4sZmo6jcjudVBH5wUhd5PggunyL6XOKlZhr9jj8+xyronOhrwTtb83aBnrlvCDbp-BSKgGv-2vW8zlXVlVdu7s2IAGVy5MAFtgJqulbKtSMqZcyXUqjaj6gNbojllquTWgA9661IEfySmxGsAh-6NwIfg1G7l35tw1obEexsQBT3YhPNgM8wBzwXjzcgJll6M2PuFH0edr7EVhA-ICX8gK7WIm-VurBpHWAoX-Bu2sgEtkSJVMow9rAYXlnAlqPgkEdQsuQKy6DbKVkGnmYaw444TSaFNGaIN5qLUFDg1ahV1pM3lizJiAAfAJjoQD1TQklasCBWL1GtJQPIbQ+IgAxCosq7jKraJuHnKoNY2JNG1FpJUgEX7kGUoBIh0C6CwMKYCfRlBlJaLkmAgk9JmoIOMUQZBnVzHdW1DSWYixQr2VmvNLB5oe51CGa47AGjJjOIEBGdQMYwpNCglALOW9ajLAhtvR4zxXj70IIfHUQi5nDJmKfGYCzgqxmaKs2+goZnWDmQ4pxdFpogimQIOO2BYRpOuJMIwXTd7QCCA+UwNidTDTwuAvxIYnlvJmNC2FAgHADCLs4x5pzPnfIEFw3gzQXn-FIkisscdHkej+e3SYGDrGjNsVk0asLJoIq+bC9xAKGXDguY4+F7yznsopBUWkPpHgMlWeswUV9xUNBlZFWs1gAD8IThFMEeM2Y0UoBXDVMagsVSpsCyClVmKAABdOSS1y4uS8VbA6dt3IfEYaPKU8sHAWyJu5XIjrMYAhAC6tgeR4AvRANYAA1Cq7yWyZRyjgk2EA98lE6ncpQBhkw6LzHEH9AAxDwxefCBHADmVc4MNz6zRvqXGyRj8U3WFggwoqlAE3KPMLkRtHqIBeuuj6v1Aag2hvDY8NyoSL7lvjXW5Nm9BRpteFmnNvD+EkhXgWllRalmDuKSOytUjq3FLreYBt9cW361yAwsBo8u05X9ZlZsYbxYDqlOUkhG7RaNqOuO7OU6M1SmzSaCdkwl4LsZoWoKxbmCDofTAp9E6X2CnA5U3d+6O5FUPYhz1p7vXOovT269-bI21I3dBpN1aP0zp-dnf9CVAPLuA6uqUeHY33wYdByYtT4OtubRAJRRUPicZ1d0qocdY6woxOGvOjMLnCbroVNRqT3RaOuApPEQR4AsGwNNTMH9KwojwgGCkVJQEMsonCsIkRWXzB4L8soDLuVNDpLwAQ3omB52aIZ8qULYW5KmBEKAXzST7ACN4WzAg2QcmcLCbwLn0SGX8MEOYVj7KAncoSXgjLgzYEE6l4TFyxMiIqBJnogEoDMHwEMJQpgBBKwAKIIFK4QAAQuEcUg7bNShkuVMQIBAU1AQLMMgTgOKwHa7gAgjmKhkCEgAFhEkgAATAAZiSRgBQhoyCBbooQMAA3DDGHBGQNt5B4pOTwN3fI0gGLl2bMRqUa3CDzSQCkIYgx4p0AEIC8w2A6hEHmC9q0utKhvY+3jPQkByDfdUiAbcBtoB-Wa+DlJ5BIdQERrMIOsxXpw8G3geAOWZAgDQEgAAHEJNgeO0BJJNVgXI+2ZDyFUEoMgZmiDtaRANlQ13bv3ce8917DPCAAAEhIoAEAAdgEGgcwJWoDmB5wIYojx7C8Bq-odrDsyDYHwLMWoZgMSLdp8oEAPO2CFbAEz2YLOQBs79Bz3gT2Xtyil21Q3cp+eC5F2LiX9ujKO7ADLne8vFciGV+EOoqv1ea4W0tunKhjOkCwMzsgFu7vi857bsA5ho+87QAIabAh8dp680rrAKuVBq417wLXOuZxkGFIQfAbz9vMBN2bhPVubever7XgY8VmC8-GwIISovzA0koGVgPheg965L2HjEJqMRAA) with the [Mithril](https://flems.io/#0=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-Xc03PTU-lWIIa-ebxNa6ia28nOyPveI1Y9nnmTp2Pdmh8Au06XdVand98uxL6DOuXguFx33SHw5G199N0Gdw3Twee2rxCem4+EaOFG14zEmd5Bt2pCHGqZJbO+da7o2bruh6XpqhgiJQPeqFnA2WAYVhOG4eOk7RmaFqzraCHtpBpBYEg0LEAR6rwduBiQPApb2BA0GkghZxwR8g7IQY+F+qW-gzPhBj+FgYAGAARhAUIHgxyDMPOtHsWcACMACsAAMhkIeS8bku0ADczKsuynJUWAzKjOM05WjaMpuvgEBhrBGpBgAPEgeA4FuuEAHLSCWMzwKQBhYM2dRKQAnsKUD8gA1rsBAGEKAQzH4EB0ApWCKaQkKaZ2-k6EFIWMk5oIuAAMoeGBUR5WJeT5iz7sQ8QZrKWBpqCnBxLmnTgccAU1aFqGBcFmzNT2VXTQh-k8E4FiwFA8lgBF4izCaRaKVgjgUOtjh0CaM24XNOCpTte0QAdvAbRQBAeFmV0CTq-m7AcLjwEl0zPYg1AMv6OmoVtD0+s9510BQozxKQUCxrhJHbbc-go6KjjPeePpo+j7qgbMwCjYgzDdrszAE+ICbE+65CwHJGB1GT9JsYzqGDSQoK016F4LPSzDwCddTwMwoFmdzbY6Nds3VfN323fdoaPXDr3vdBDBfZDZy-QCANA09JqAZGRPc9D6uwya8OIxoHioxDssTJjEDY1AuPPebwGW4zpPk2LlPUxguI7UBSAM7LzOs+zwCc5N+s80NFy+0gws4mLJ6S9L33uu08sq0rtWQ-5imHDFFKA8DJpgPsilpP7uHW7ttsgIp8AUp3lDgvYJ1Jc3qHM2lsDpWTkzTAs+fBhCBJEgiSLEYzQnbLz6ZUy1CwU8oocy8TaztAruGLbsxcV-AVfHwYVXwwry3KxgCbiuMjQQJfWVgG18yeXg3mwT1S+jh+rAHXsNHe40-KVRWuxW6mw34fzZgpcczAH6lxujA4m5dK5ClbhrE0PclJdwoH3OgA8h5MwwFtDKZNV5xVTmATeBA+JkiPjPRafFz44IwNfNB98S5bmflQhqBgmJi2-rKDqf8upNl6sA10YCxgjWDhASBXMfrTSDrmZgMkAA+ujyLNQYllMcMB5IzDDFgPwyxNIgHaHwuqGAX4uHHApH+WJXJURwqfVqNocIIJIEgrxWIxFYCoo45x3JeQADVpEygWIosAGpJHymci4IsMgyyxXmKRGsScSJTDuAJPEkIYRwkXvAZe7o6GJOYBkqK5YFi5P3jqGWVIaQUhQleaRsigEgI4iotst4ulnDSfQkgkIZS5NrDvcO1Y5izByS2GsAB+ci4zgq2gMH6E01l2JjIAMKeGiKELQUybRgCELM3JABdPZuF2m0kWCrTBjN-KIjVm3faJoxaKT1q7fyaVPka0xCAX5FACqXRAAYAA1BsyE08KIzhtCaQ+18sHxUCHCZ6ABiecI8aHAHqbmRpJpPEopAGimeuFXLUp+joLA6LFZpSZe6QFeBgWw1BeCyF844XrwRSaHx4TKVsOTmyzFCQeC4vxVQ0e48iWRRJaQRFwqKVUvFahHxdKDYMtZfSlldL2Wcv2tykqELEBQthfCopIAAmfxFRq12BtJXYpNHi6FBKx5k2JVkxF9qgnqrFc6nUAaCCOU1bqxlRqdCGs1cavBXKfnmt5dC-laZBUgFCY64Nzr-Kuule62V1DvWKuLMqxF2ag36twqEnVN89UxrjdzKqiJ9X+SOQ4U5sQVET23iow+GzQRk0SZ0IuZcBGmSDNHBMQjbIcgMAAWQgGQMAeBkG9RqBSTiWZhSkFFJEkSeYBl5DoGSSJiSZRSgYMwVMfMxgLCPeSMZO83EnqKMwMAAoMALD-HUP417mBKj8HgJ4ZI-hPsibE7yMoeQMGg2GBJDCNi2XUIwZgbheZOEHhgYodBoJaAWEgUgsB9jiC0MwCWABRGA5H4CtCSoaRF17UV-F-v-ViHwz0IbYwM3MapX2sIsmsLgIA0OTBgI4SQx1lJQFE5AGADDJC6V0gADlQIZOxDQpDiEkIB-w8A6BybUBoAkkh2UYHSgYBIUBnpxCSgIKS795xYsLSAAz8AGAZlZPsPY6UCDMDQzkaYCAEiBdDErOIwW4CFBKDTWAoY9aqzwEgZ6LGQCbAcRgZLqWfmOEGjUK6fD5PQBi+mSQAAmVAFWADMdibntCAA) version with [flems.io](http://flems.io).